# How can I access a embedded video that doesn't have a url in HTML

Tags: html5-video

I was trying to clone a website so there was a video element in the page so I tried to find it and download via inspect but I it does'nt show a ref link .. it shows like it's stored in a folder or something can anyone suggest how can I download that video

this is the code embedded with video (WEBSITE: wolves (https://www.wolves.co.uk/)

CODE :

```
<div class="hero__video-wrapper" data-desktop-video="/media/27694/boubacar-leeds.mp4" data-desktop-video-type="video/mp4">
```

I tried by inspecting elements to find the video url but couldn't find any url all i found is a folder location . I was expecting to download the video for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"It shows like it's **stored in a folder** or something can anyone suggest how can I download that video"*

**Solution**: 
You're very close.
Just prepend `https://wolves-cdn.azureedge.net/` to the URL shown in `data-desktop-video=`.

example link for your video:
https://wolves-cdn.azureedge.net/media/27694/boubacar-leeds.mp4

> *"I was expecting to download the video for educational purposes"*

Oh shuddup and just steal the copyrighted online content already...!!!
Just joking. I'll help you cos I think that video is downloadable under "Fair Use" policy...